# nginx rewrite of cname host mapping url paths

Tags: nginx, dns, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

There is currently an app that is using cname host mapping with a third party app

the hostname for the third party app is `mycompany.partner.com`
and the current cname host map under my domain `help.mycompany.com`

so current routing is below

```
users => cloudflare DNS(help.mycompany.com) => cname host mapping(mycompany.partner.com) => partner app
```

now i want to do this

```
                                                             => cname host mapping(mycompany.partner.com) => partner app
                                                            |
users => cloudflare DNS(help.mycompany.com) => my nginx =>  |
                                                            |
                                                             => my frontend app
```

**is this possible?**

So basically i want all traffic to come to my own app via nginx now and then i route some traffic based on url path to the third party app and others to my frontend app

how can i achieve this with nginx? below are the url paths i want to route

> this routes to my frontend app

```
help.mycompany.com/app/test1                  => http://localhost:500/app/test1  
help.mycompany.com/app/test2/test3            => http://localhost:500/app/test2/test3
help.mycompany.com/app/parameter?key=check    => http://localhost:500/app/parameter?key=check
```

> this rewrites/routes to partner app

```
help.mycompany.com/app/partner1               => https://mycompany.partner.com/app/partner1 
help.mycompany.com/app/discuss/check          => https://mycompany.partner.com/app/discuss/check

and all other paths
```

location block to route all url paths to the frontend app is below

```
location ^~ / {

    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:500;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

but now i need to split some url paths to the partner app as stated above

so basically all traffic will pass through nginx as i will point DNS for help.mycompany.com to now point to my nginx reverse proxy and then routes and rewrites the url

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create different location for uri paths. For Example:

```
location /app/partner1 {
   proxy_pass https://mycompany.partner.com;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_redirect off;
}
location /app/discuss/check {
   proxy_pass https://mycompany.partner.com;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_redirect off;
}
```

In above case holds good for REST calls where are not trying to render static js or html files, which can be domain specific. You are rendering static js or html , trying adding those paths also to the domain there are present.

If you want to redirect specific location to particular domain, please take a look the example below:

```
location /app/discuss/check {
   return 301 https://mycompany.partner.com$request_uri;
}
```

In this case all the specified uri will get redirect to the domain one specify.

Remember to add the generic path, if nothing matches it will go to this one. Example below:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:500;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Below is the example for a sample conf.

```
server {
  listen       8888;
  server_name  localhost;

  # default path
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:500;
  }
  # third party proxy paths
  location /app/discuss/check {
    proxy_pass https://mycompany.partner.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  location /app/partner1 {
    proxy_pass https://mycompany.partner.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  location /test {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "All Good !";
  }
  location /search {
    proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID cluster1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    
    proxy_pass   https://www.google.com;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Hit `http://localhost:8888/search?q=zenduty` on your browser to test. localhost nginx server will proxy the request on google search. One can add extra headers if needed, will proxying.

Comment: I am trying to match certain specific paths to internal service and then ALL other paths to the third party app with the cname mapping. so not sure if you got my question well

Comment: you can provide the `server_name help.mycompany.com;` while defining you conf. You will receive request on help.mycompany.com only, then it will get redirected or forwarded according to the conf.

Comment: so i have to have different server_names? you mind updating the answer to see how this will look like? will be greatly appreciated....nginx will route same servern_name just that some path will go to internal app and some to third party

Comment: updated answer with sample conf.

Comment: how do i catch the paths with regex that need to go to the frontend app http://localhost:500? that is why i listed those paths that need to route to it. also i need to now match all other paths to the third party app. that is what am trying to do. think i tried to explain it very well in the question

Comment: will be great if you can use the endpoints and paths in my question to make things not confusing, like i said match certain paths to internal frontend app and then all other paths to the cname host mapping thirdparty app..all i need help with. thanks for helping with this. appreciate t

Comment: can you update answer to use regex as described in the question to catch the url paths? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    we can create multiple HTTP and server blocks and we can separate the traffic according to the path.
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain application/json;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  server_tokens off;


  map $host $record_name {
    "~^(?<record>[^.]+)\.your\.yourcomapany\.com$" "$record";
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourcompany.com;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    set $backend https://$record_name.yourapp-oryourcompanybacckend;

   

    location /{
      if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
    
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_pass $backend$request_uri;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

#      proxy_intercept_errors on;
#      error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 =302 http://maintenance.yourcompany.com/;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /healthy {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }
  }


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourcompanysecondpath;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    set $backend http://yourapp-oryourcompany-secondbacckend;

    

    location /{
      if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
    
      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_pass $backend$request_uri;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

#      proxy_intercept_errors on;
#      error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 =302 http://maintenance.company.com/;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /healthy {
        access_log off;
        return 200 "healthy\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: i want the same `server_name` certain paths proxy_pass to `http://localhost:500` and all others proxy_pass to third-party website `https://mycompany.partner.com` what i need help with is with the regex in location block to the different paths logic, please read question to understand. thanks